# In circuitpython and micropython is it advisable to import dependencies on the fly?

Tags: python, performance, microcontroller, micropython, adafruit-circuitpython

Would it be okay to display a loading screen before importing large dependencies or do imports get processed in some way before any code is run?

Comment: Might be better off asking in their [forum](https://forum.micropython.org/).

Comment: In Python a module gets imported when its `import` call is executed for the first time.

Comment: I think only you can determine if it's "okay". Does it improve the user experience for your project? Then it's probably okay. There are a number of Python best practices that it's okay to toss out the window when working with micropython; you decide which ones are important to you.

Comment: Did you do some benchmarks? Their result should give you some hints.

Comment: @KlausD. Okay thanks, that's what I was wondering. Do you want to make it an answer to get the points?

Comment: Where are you planning to display the loading screen?